# How to run the same PHP script on different remote servers?

Tags: php, php-7

I have a native PHP script on **`www.principaldomaine.com`**

And I want to run this unique script on each customer's dashboard:

- **`www.client1.com`**
- **`www.client2.com`**
- **`www.client3.com`**

etc.

To do this, I used the native PHP function **`include_one()`**, like this:

```
$host_client = (isset ($_ SERVER ['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER ['HTTPS'] === 'on'? "https": "http"). ": // {$_SERVER [ 'HTTP_HOST']} {$_SERVER [ 'REQUEST_URI']}";

$include = 'https://principaldomain.com/script_client.php?key=5458978&host='.$host_client;

if (!@include_once($include)) {
    echo $error_msg;
}
else
    include_once($include);
```

But the problem is that the module **`allow_url_include`** is not activated and my web hosting "PlanetHoster" does not allow it for security reasons.

I tried to activate it with HTACCESS like this:
**`php_flag allow_url_include On`**

But it did not work as well because allow_url_include is a PHP_INI_SYSTEM directive.

I thought about using **`$ _SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`** manually in **`include_once ()`** like this:

```
$include = '/home/MyNameHosting/public_html/script_client.php';

if (! @include_once($include)) {
    echo $error_msg;
}
else
    include_once($ include);
```

**=> And it works! but that's not enough because I could not pass the variables "`key`" and "`host`" like this:**

```
$include = '/home/MyNameHosting/public_html/script_client.php?key=5458978&host='.$host_client;
```

Do you have any idea how to pass GET variables in this situation?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Files you include can access the variables declared before. So just use `$host_client` in the included file. (script_client.php)

Comment: include the file without any querystring and, from within this included file, issue a HTTP request ( cURL, sockets etc ) to obtain the necessary data from your `principaldomain.com`

Comment: `$include = '/home/MyNameHosting/public_html/script_client.php?key=5458978&host='.$host_client;` doesn't work because **script_client.php** is run on **www.principaldomaine.com** to do `$_GET[key]` and `$_GET[host]` 
Thank you a lot for replay

Comment: How can use cURL sockets in this situation ? can you detail the code please

Comment: _“$include = '/home/MyNameHosting/public_html/script_client.php?key=5458978&host='.$host_client; doesn't work because script_client.php is run on www.principaldomaine.com”_ - no, it is not. You are including the script via the server file system here, and that is something _completely different_, than requesting a script via HTTP. Remove the query string part, query strings do not exist in the file system.

Comment: As said, your script automatically has access to all variables in the scope of the “main” script, where you are doing this include via the file system. So either have `$foo = 'bar'` in your main script, and then access `$foo` in the included script; or, if you insist on getting the value from $_GET, then _set_ them beforehand in the main script - `$_GET['foo'] = 'bar'`

Comment: Thank You very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

I think what you need is to execute a HTTP request on another server. One solution could be to do it like that :

```php
// With Guzzle
// Documentation here : http://docs.guzzlephp.org
$res = $client->request('GET', 'https://principaldomain.com/script_client.php', [
    'query' => ['key' => '5458978', 'host' => $host_client]
]);

// With Curl
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://principaldomain.com/script_client.php?key=5458978&host=" . urlencode($host_client),
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

I described two ways to achieve your goal, one using Guzzle, a modern PHP library you need to add to your project, and another one using the classic curl library, probably already available.

For Guzzle, documentation is here  [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org).

### Security concerns

You "can" require or include a remote PHP script, but it will mostly add a lot of security issues and you probably don't really want to do that. That's why, I assume what you want to do is not exactly what you asked.

And that is also why, I will not explain how to do it. Because only developers knowing exactly what they are doing should include/require remote scripts directly. 99.9999% of the time, what you need is to do secured HTTP requests.

Comment: Thank you Mr Vinks

The purpose of my script is to display targeted content for my clients on their dashboards without going through the main site.

 I still plan to use HTTPS and I want to retrieve some settings from each client's server to automate the targeted display. 

Otherwise, I have to change the same code for 100 clients for each update or improvement of the script! 

According to you there is a good practice to do it? because the operation of the script is similar to a client-server service

Thank you a lot